# How to send sms in laravel to all users if users table city matches with services table city?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I want to send sms to all users in laravel if **service's table city** field  matches with **user's city field**.

Take a example:-

> if i submit a form for a service by selecting a city, then it will
>   match with the users city field, if it matches then automatically send
>   a sms to all users with same city..

Comment: So what you have tired?

Comment: I didn't tried yet, can you please send me the code for this function

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is how this site works.. Try to code it yourself at first.

Heres a little help: 
First get a query of all the service's table city list and then get the current user's city field and see where they match.
And then you have to subscribe to an SMSservice to send these sms messages.